# partially deploy Dacpack

Tags: c#, dacpac

I have a dacpac file, generated from a DB or DB project. This dacpac contains of course tables, stored procedures, views, etc.

I want to create a new DB with just some objects from the dacpac, not all of them.
I have the list of objects, tables in my case.

I want to know of to ignore from dacpac objects, or create another dacpac with just a sub-group of objects, or maybe extract the corresponding sql script of my target objects.

any advice on this ?
thanks

Comment: [DacFx Public Model Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/12/23/dacfx-public-model-tutorial.aspx) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the

[AgileSqlClub SqlPackage Deployment Filter](https://agilesqlclub.codeplex.com/).

Here the related blog post:

https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/HOWTO-Filter-Dacpac-Deployments